# Significant crashes on Ubuntu 20.04. Unable to use it at all

Tags: 20.04, crash

I am dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 next to a host Windows 10. ~100GB partition for Linux with 50% free space. This is a Dell XPS 15 9570.

I am experiencing a crash that kicks me out to the login screen. I can work for about 2 minutes before it crashes. If I just sit there, it won't crash, nor will Terminal cause a crash. Opening up other apps, like Files or a browser, cause an almost immediate crash.

I changed my swap size to 4GB, but that did not resolve the problem.

All my software is up to date including the new 20.04.1 release.

I tried running the fsck utility from a Ubuntu Live USB, but I am not sure if it did anything.

I'm not sure if this is related, but I get an initramfs unpacking error during startup. I ran `sudo update-initramfs -u` but it didn't resolve the issue.

Error message on startup:

[image: error message on startup]

I'm pretty new to Linux, so I'm not sure which logs to include (or how to find them), but I'd gladly include them if someone tells me what to find.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Firefox which stopped much of the crashing. I'm now consistently getting the same type of crashes when using the Libre Office suite of products (Writer, etc) to the point where I cannot do any work when using them.

I am going to resolve this question as caused by specific programs (FIrefox and LibreOffice), although I was unable to resolve the initramfs issue (seems to be a separate issue).